# Google chart - reformat variable not working

Tags: javascript, charts

In Google chart-  when i call the function to remove comma from variable from input , it wont work.
 What i want is result from  ldsalary(without comma) update in Google chart. ldsalary value is calculated and shown while onkeyup. It will be changing.

update : made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acnu1zec/5/)

onkeyup:

```
document.getElementById('cal').onkeyup=function(){
calculator();
drawChart();
```

reformat function:

```
function reformat(str) {
    while (str.search(",") >= 0) {
        str = (str + "").replace(',', '');
    }
    return str;
};
```

Calculator function, this updates ldsalary with new value:

```
function calculator(){
.........
var jldsalary = document.getElementById("ldsalary");
 xm = a * Math.pow(1 + jasincrease / 100, b);
jldsalary.value = rounding(xm).toLocaleString(); 
}
```

Chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rage = 55 ;
var slry = 5000;

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
    rage =document.getElementById('rage').value *1;
    var xxx = document.getElementById('ldsalary').value *1;
    // if i add this google chart wont show.
    slry.value =reformat(xxx); // without reformat, there will be ',' value.

   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0], [rage,slry],
    [100, 0]
  ]);

  var options = {
    curveType: 'function',
    width: 500,
    height: 200,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Age'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Amount'
    }
  };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Its been a day doing all kinds of solutions. Advance thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in reformat().

```
function reformat(str) {
    return parseInt(str.replace(',', ''));
}
```

Now it works: as value in input box changes , google graph too changes.

Answer (score 0):

as per your code, you have defined `slry` as a variable, and trying to use `spry.value`, which is not valid at all, change:

```
...
slry.value =reformat(xxx); //its just a variable not input element
```

to

```
...
slry = reformat(xxx);
```

Comment: sorry. chrome doesnt show error.  
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: error is here on WHILE line    
:function reformat(str) {
    while (str.search(",") >= 0) {
        str = (str + "").replace(',', '');
    }
    return str;
};

Comment: @AsherMalcom your line :: var xxx = document.getElementById('ldsalary').value *1; returns NaN because you are trying to multiply comma separated value by 1, try removing the multiply part..

Comment: When i removed the *1 , not getting value if ldsalary is changed. Its fixed with var slry = 5000; . But error is gone .